# request has no response when visit nodePort service

Tags: kubernetes

I deployment a kubernetes cluster with 5 nodes: matser worker1 worker2 worker3 worker4.

And I create a deployment with 1 replica, it was arranged on worker4, expose port 7777

create a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-test
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 7777
      nodePort: 31000
```

After create service, I send a request to worker4:31000/test ,it responses immediately.

But when I request other nodes on 31000, such as master:31100/test , worker1:31100/test. It has no response, and sometime it will response, but it cost such a long time.

**when I use lsof to show port usage, it different**

```
[root@worker4 ~]# lsof -i:31000
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
wrapper 5251 root    5u  IPv4  33957      0t0  TCP localhost:32000->localhost:31000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    5355 root   13u  IPv6  35851      0t0  TCP localhost:31000->localhost:32000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
kube-prox 9679 root   13u  IPv6 3746350      0t0  TCP *:31000 (LISTEN)
```

so how can I visit nodePort service on other nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodeport goes through extra network hop and uses IP table load balancing at L4 layer provided by kube proxy.So it's expected to be slow particularly if you access a pod from a a node where it's not scheduled. Also kube proxy need to be running in nodes from where you want to access a pod via nodeport service.

I would suggest to use a reverse proxy such as nginx as ingress or L7 load balancer for faster performance.

Comment: thanks.and  if I want to visit the node port fast, what should I config?

Comment: If you want fast then you need to look at alternative of nodeport such as L7 load balancer or ingress. There is no way to make nodeport faster as its intrinsically slow